# Do I have a unique solution for this system of two equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

I beleve the following to be true, but I cannot prove it.

1.) Suppose that f(x,y) and g(x,y) are continues over $R^2$.
2.) The functions $f_x(x,y)$, $f_y(x,y)$, $g_x(x,y)$ and $g_y(x,y)$ exist and
are  continuous.
3) $ \forall \epsilon > 0 $ the following is true:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_x(x + \epsilon,y) &>=& f_x(x,y) \\
f_y(x,y + \epsilon) &>=& f_y(x,y) \\
g_y(x + \epsilon,y) &>=& g_y(x,y) \\
g_y(x,y + \epsilon) &>=& g_y(x,y) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
4) There exist a point $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f(x_0,y_0) = 0$
and $g(x_0,y_0) = 0$

If all of the above are true then $(x_0, y_0)$ is the unique solution to
the system of equations:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y) &=& 0 \\
g(x,y) &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
It seems to me that somebody should have proved this already. If you think I
am wrong, could somebody come up with a counter example?

Comment: A remark: As the two functions don't interact whatsoever, it is enough to consider just the function $f$. The three assumptions can be summarized by saying that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $f_x$ is increasing in $x$, and $f_y$ is increasing in $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y) = x+y$, which obviously satisfies all the assumptions. Then the whole line $x-y = 0$ is a solution of $f(x,y) = 0$, giving a counterexample.

Comment: I claim that your counter example fails condition 3.The partial derivative with respect to $\phi$ is not increasing. A better way to state that is the following requirement is not being meet: $g_y(x,y + \epsilon) &>=& g_y(x,y)$.Also, $f$ and $g$ both have to have a value of $0$ at the same point. That is how they interact.

Comment: Ah! It's the partial derivatives, not the functions themselves. Let me think 5 minutes about it, then.

Comment: @Bob Ok, this counterexample should work.